# Convert dictionary to object (or copy to local object var)

Tags: python, object, dictionary, web2py

I want to reuse some code that someone else wrote.

The code is a long iteration over an array of objects and their properties. the data comes from a built-in function.

I provide the same data structure through ajax (as JSON) so python(web2py) turns it into a dict.

In order to keep using the same long code untouched, I need a way to convert the current element from dictionary, to object.

The reason: the properties are written as `Obj.prop` and no as `Obj["prop"]`.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class ObjectDict(dict):
    """
    Object like dict, every dict[key] can be visited by dict.key
    """

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.__getitem__(name)
```

Comment: Note, web2py already includes the [`Storage` class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27681083/440323), which does this.

Answer (score 3):

web2py includes a `Storage` class that has this behavior.

```
from gluon.storage import Storage
mystorage = Storage(dict(key1=1, key2=2))
mystorage.key1
```

Several of the web2py API objects are `Storage` objects (e.g., `request`, `response`, `session`).

Answer (score 2):

There's a package that does exactly this called attrdict (I'm using it without any issues):
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrdict/1.2.0

Example (copied from attrdict doc):

```
>>> from attrdict import AttrDict
>>> a = AttrDict({'foo': 'bar'})
>>> a.foo
'bar'
>>> a['foo']
'bar'
```

A benefit to using this is that dictionaries that are not flat also work (as long as you always access by the property, and not with the standard dict syntax):

```
>>> a = AttrDict({'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}})
>>> a.foo.bar
'baz'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Bunch class. There are various recipes around, [pydanny's](http://pydanny.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/loving-bunch-class.html) looks good.